# Apt-get not working after removing gnupg

Tags: apt, dpkg, gnupg

I just removed gnupg and broke my system. Right now for example apt-get is not working anymore. Any ideas how i can get it working again or i can reinstall pgp without apt-get?

Comment: https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use livecd to chroot to your system and reinstall gnupg from that.
There is an [article on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) on how to do that.

Steps taken from that article:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.
2. Press Ctrl-Alt-F1
3. sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
5. sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
6. sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
7. sudo chroot /mnt
8. apt-get update
9. apt-get upgrade

But instead of step 9 above - you will use `apt-get install gnupg`

Comment: DNS wasn't working so could not make the updates with apt-get update. I had to change the nameserver by deleting the resolv.conf with rm /etc/resolv.conf then creating a new (the currentwas read only) with touch  /etc/resolv.conf and opening it with nano /etc/resolv.conf and write the adress of my router "nameserver 192.168.178.1" in it. Afterwards "apt-get update" worked fine and after using "apt-get -f install" and a reboot my system is running again. Thank you very much!